# Design a timer circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I need a  time circuit to switch off lamps(6 lamps of 16 watt each) after some time. Time should be adjustable(In secs like 30s or 90s).The lamps are fluorescent lamps. The  circuit should also have a beeper to beep after the required time. If it is possible please add a digital clock timer to show time or some audrino or something. Please help me. I am not into electronics but I really need this for a project.

Comment: I see you've already tagged the 555 timer IC in your question so I'm sure you're already looking at using it in the "monostable" configuration. It would help if you edit your question to add how you plan to trigger the event. Off the top of my head you'll need 6 relays and 1 or more transistors to trigger them from the 555 output.

Comment: Sorry mate I don't know what 555 is. It just popped up in tag suggestions. Please design this circuit for me.

Comment: @MadhavAgarwal This is not a free design service.

Comment: Right, so could you recommend any site to post this ?

Comment: As @Hearth said, we can help but first please do your research. As one of the most popular hobbiest IC's, there are plenty of tutorials and resources for the 555, check out https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/555-timer-monostable-circuit/

Comment: We help you get unstuck when you are designing it yourself, have earnestly done an appropriate amount of learning on your own, and have reached an impasse.   P.S. given how frequently you'll be starting these fluorescent lights, you're going to want programmed-start ballasts.  They will keep the lights from wearing out quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I would forgo using any analog components for the time-keeping process and just use a microcontroller. The benefits are as follows:

- Simple to modify/adjust time intervals
- Easy interface into 7-seg display / beeper / lamps
- Good timer accuracy/range

The only analog circuits you would need are simple transistor drivers for the lamps. Using a microcontroller (like your mentioned arduino) would nicely separate the functionality into behavioural blocks. This helps organize your project, when debugging it, and when showing it off.

---

If you're dead set on the 555 it will be harder. Long time constants require large capacitors and/or large resistors. This may cause leakage currents from the 555 to cause timing issues. Additionally, component tolerances will muck with your timer accuracy. Depending on your adjustable timer setting, implementation might get even more complicated.

Comment: You don't even need transistor drivers for the lamps. All you need is an ability for the Arduino to control something that can switch power to the lamps, like an X10 light controller, RiB relay, Aube, or whatevs.